# django chart.js can't use {{% for loop%}}

Tags: django, django-templates

I am a newbie to django, I don’t know why I can use for loop in javascript in other people’s teaching, but I can’t use for loop in javascript like this. Hope someone can tell me why.

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [{% for i in myobject %}"{{ labels }}",{% endfor %}],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: '{{ data }}',
    
            }]
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: labels: [{% for i in myobject %}"{{ labels }}",{% endfor %}],

this is my code

Comment: You might use the `|json_script` template filter: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/rendering-into-javascript.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know how to do that
labels: [{% for i in myobject %}"{{ labels|safe }}",{% endfor %}]
Did i edit this right?

Comment: no, the first code fragments show ways *not* to pass JSON values to the template, since these can result in running arbitrary code at the client side.

Comment: so, i can't use the {%for loop %} on chart.js is because that?

Comment: you simply should *not* do that... In a template you only write *rendering* logic, not *business* logic. The view should "prepare" data in such a way that it can be rendered effectively, the template should not do all sorts of tricks to render it correctly.

Comment: but i need to render the value to js to make a bar chart，if i don't render to template , i don't know how can i do

Comment: I refer to this person’s teaching plan and he uses for loops in js
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OL5n06kO_w

Comment: but as specified in the article regarding this, it is unsafe. It means that people can "forge" labels such that these are rendered and performed at another's person browser (hence JavaScript injection), you should not allow this since it is a serious security vulnerability.

Comment: the idea of the `|json_script` template filter is exactly to *avoid* such security breaches.

Comment: OK, i will try it. Thanks for your help.